# PhoneGap/JQuery mobile - Navigation issue, only on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile, navigation, phonegap

I am creating a mobile app (PhoneGap/JQuery mobile), for learning a new language. I have an issue with my navigation on the mobile device. I am able to get it to work on the browser.

**The structure of the app**.
I have a folder called chapters. This folder contains all the chapters (1,2,3).
Each chapter has its own exercises and grammar files.

Example of structure.
chapters/1/exercises/exercise1.html (chapter 1, exercise 1)
chapters/2/exercises/exercise1.html (chapter 2, exercise 1)

The navigation is included on all pages.
Its a hamburger menu that slides out. 
Location of navigation.
shared/_nav.html

exercise1.html, include navigation section.

```
  $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){       
            $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="panel"]').load("../../../shared/_nav.html", function(){ 
                $(this).parent().enhanceWithin('create');
                $('#chapter1').collapsible('expand');
                $(this).parent().enhanceWithin('create');
            }); 
    });
```

Section of the main navigation. (shared/_nav.html file)

```
<div id="chapter1" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-collapsed="true">
            <h3>1</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><h4><a href="http://11.4.33.55:3007/chapters/1/exercises/exercise1.html" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false">Exercise 1.1</a></h4></li>
                <li><h4><a href="http://11.4.33.55:3007/chapters/1/exercises/exercise2.html" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false">Exercise 1.2</a></h4></li>
                <li><h4><a href="http://11.4.33.55:3007/chapters/1/exercises/exercise3.html" data-transition="slide" data-ajax="false">Exercise 1.3</a></h4></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I want to keep my exercises, in separate html files because they are quit extensive.

I have tried many different ways of writing the link. But could not get it to work.

Final question.
I want to publish the app on the Apple app store. Would a folder structure like mine, be a problem with getting the app approved?

Any help would be appreciated.